# Nginx not getting file available on route through Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, nginx, ember-cli-mirage

Works on local and github pages but with nginx. Even on nginx I can properly get the json file from the browser, just not within the ember app on nginx.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
      return $.getJSON('data/contributors.json')
  }
})
```

Results in this error only on Nginx:

```
server.js:76 Mirage: Your Ember app tried to GET 'data/contributors.json', but there was no route defined to handle this request. Define a route that matches this path in your mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?
```

location config on nginx:

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
            try_files $uri /index.html;

    }

    location /data {
            try_files $uri /contributors.json
    }
```

config/environment.js

```
if (environment === 'internal') {
ENV.baseURL = '/'
ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
  enabled: true
}
ENV.mirageNamespace = '<ip address>'
ENV.isProd = true
ENV.isDemo = true
```

}

Any help in resolving the error is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Mirage enabled, which is intercepting network requests and handling them itself. If you're deploying your app, you should be doing a build with `--environment production`, which by default disables Mirage.

If you're enabling Mirage manually for some reason but you don't want this behavior, you can add `this.passthrough()` at the bottom of your `mirage/config.js` file to allow the request to actually hit the network.

- [enabled docs](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/server-configuration/#enabled)
- [passthrough docs](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/server-configuration/#passthrough)

Comment: I have this but it doesn't work. The Nginx server does work if I just do `ember build` though... (I also added my environment.js file to the question)

Comment: Is your API/ Ember Data Adapter's host specified to something other than the domain serving the ember app? If so you need to specify that domain in the call to `passthrough`, e.g. `this.passthrough('my.api.com/**')`